# Broadcom wireless network driver broke i3wm

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, i3-wm

I just installed Broadcom wireless network driver on my Ubuntu 22.04 computer, so that I won't have to rely on a USB adapter anymore to connect to the internet, but it didn't work. I still could not connect to wireless networks and also, my i3wm started behaving strangely. When I open my terminal with `mod + return` I'm just greeted with a blurred portion of my screen which seems to be from picom trying to blur the background when I open an app and even though  I dont't see any text or cursor  I can tell that my terminal is running and if i type the `exit` command, and press Enter the blurred window disappears as if the terminal just closed, so I uninstalled the driver (though I still have the zip file) to see if things would go back to normal, but they didn't. Furthermore I can't even connect to the internet through USB tethering with my phone anymore, so I'm unable to reinstall the driver.

I just realized that my problem might be because when I rebooted my system after installing the driver, I only enrolled my MOK and didn't change the Secure Boot settings because when I run `lspci --vv` on my terminal (using regular GNOME) the capability section of the hardware showing there shows `<access denied>`.

Also, when I switch to gnome at login instead of i3 I can open my terminal and other apps normally but I still can't connect to any wireless networks.

Comment: I just realised that my problem might be because when I rebooted my system after installing the driver, I only enrolled my MOK and didn't change secure boot settings cuz when I run `lspci --vv` on my terminal (using regular gnome) the capability section of the hardware showing there shows`<access denied>`

Comment: Your question makes no sense, possibly because of bad speech-to-text. Please edit it for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out I made quite a lot of errors, hopefully it should be better now.